# Mongodb cursor emits "end" too soon (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream

I have a collection with 150 000 items. 
I'm using cursor.stream() to iterate over them.

The "end" event always gets fired way too early, about 15-20 000 items are never streamed.

There is no error event or any other error / exception.

The cursor is created like this:

```
return this.conn.find({},

    {
        timeout: false,
        batchSize: 50,
        maxTimeMS: 0,
        fields: {
            field1: 1,
            field2: 1
        }
    });
```

My code looks something like this (I removed several parts to keep it short, this is kinda pseudo code)

```
var cursor = self.db.SomeCollection.getCursor();
cursor.limit(0);
cursor.skip(0);
cursor.maxTimeMS(0);
cursor.batchSize(50);

var stream = cursor.stream();

cursor.count(function(err,cnt) {

    self.logger.info('Processing %d items',cnt);

    var bar = new ProgressBar(':bar :percent complete (:elapseds)', {
        total: cnt,
        width: 100
    });

    stream.on('data',function(item) {

        stream.pause();

        self.db.OtherCollection.findStuff(item.prop, function(err,user) {

            // some processing...

            self.db.OtherCollection.updateStuff(item.ptop,data,function(err,upd) {

                // more processing...

                bar.tick();
                stream.resume();

            });
        });
    });

    stream.on('end',function() {
        console.log();
        self.logger.info('Done');
        process.exit(0);
    });

    stream.on('error',function(err) {
        self.error('Mongodb operation failed',err);
    });

});
```

Is this a bug? How can I stream all items?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm facing a similar problem.